# How to validate old password when i change a new password

Tags: jquery

I have a form for editing a user account, there I give input-field contains the new password and the old password. If the new password field is not filled in, the data will be stored, and if the new password field filled in the old password field must be filled, then how do I have to provide validation? The New password is not equal to old password.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Current Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="currentPassword" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">New Password</label><input type="password" name="newPassword" id="newPassword" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: You need to provide some sample code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Check if new password field is filled. If it is filled, check old password field, and if it is empty or equals to new password, show an error and prevent form submit.

Comment: i think you have to provide the html along with script you are using in the form.

Answer (score 1):

```
Considering you HTML to be something like this:-

<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Current Password</label>
     <input id="oldpassword" type="password" name="currentPassword" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">New Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="newPassword" id="newPassword" class="form-control">
</div>

Javascript Code:-

if ($.trim($('#newPassword').val()) != "" && $.trim($(#oldpassword').val()) == "")
 { 
     return false; // Display error message
 }
else if  ($.trim($('#newPassword').val()) != "" && $.trim($(#oldpassword').val()) != "")
{
    if ($.trim($('#newPassword').val()) != $.trim($(#old`enter code here`password').val())
     {
        //Show error message that password doesn't match
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below HTML & Javascript code with Jquery remote validation

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password:<i class="star-requird">*</i></label>
    <i class="clearfix"></i>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"id="password"    value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Confirm password:<i class="star-requird">*</i></label>
    <i class="clearfix"></i>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password"  id="confirm_password" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Old password:<i class="star-requird">*</i></label>
    <i class="clearfix"></i>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="old_password" id="old_password" value="">
    </div>  
    <input class="btn green-btn btn-margin-none" type="submit" value="Reset"   title="Reset" onClick="return formvalidationReset();">

     function formvalidationReset() {
     $("#reset_form").validate({
     rules: {
     password: {required: true},
     confirm_password: {required: true, equalTo: "#password"},
     old_password: {
     required: true,
     remote: {
     url: "matchOldPassword.php',
     type: "post",
     data: {
     old_password: function() {
     return $("#old_password").val();
    },
    csrf_dw_name : $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
    }
    }
    }
    },
    messages: {
    password: {required: "Please enter passowrd"},
    confirm_password: {required: "Please enter confirm password",
    equalTo: "Your passwords & confirm password does not match.",},
    old_password: {required: "Please enter old password",
    remote: "Old password does not match."}
    },
    errorElement: "p"
    });
    }
```